# MemSQL geospatial union of polygons

Tags: union, geospatial, singlestore

Will the new MemSQL version be able to calculate the union of polygons? For example calcuate the border of two adjacent or even intercepting polygons?

```
+----+
|    |
|  +-+--+
+--+-+  |
   |    |
   +----+
```

to

```
+----+
|    |
|    +--+
+--+    |
   |    |
   +----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemSQL 4 includes topological functions (eg, geography_intersects()) that return a boolean, and measurement functions like distance and length. It does not yet have constructor functions like intersection(), which would output a polygon as you describe. It's on the roadmap, though.